# averageifs function returns #div/0

Tags: excel

suppose that  we have following  date

```
Region                 Profits (Thousands)
East                    45.678
West                    23.789
North                   -4.789
South(New Office)            0
MidWest                  9.678
```

i want to calculate average  for west and Midwest  regions,and suppose that  F and G are names of columns,then i have typed

```
=AVERAGEIFS(G5:G9,F5:F9,F6,F5:F9,F9)
```

but result is div by zero,so please help me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cell that meets the criteria you're asking for. You're actually asking for the average of profits where the corresponding value in F5:F9 is equal to "West" **and** "MidWest".

If you want to get the average of profits where the corresponding value in F5:F9 is equal to "West" **or** "MidWest", you can use something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(G5:G9,(F5:F9=F6)+(F5:F9=F9))/SUMPRODUCT((F5:F9=F6)+(F5:F9=F9))
```

Comment: please look there then http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx

Comment: @datodatuashvili I'm not sure why you are linking me to the docs of AVERAGEIF?

Comment: because there written like this

Comment: =AVERAGEIF(A2:A6,"=*West",B2:B6)

Comment: @datodatuashvili There, they used `AVERAGEIF` and not `AVERAGEIFS`, and there, they hard-coded the formula. Sure, you can use `=*West` instead in the `AVERAGEIFS` formula so that it is actually: `=AVERAGEIFS(G5:G9,F5:F9,"=*West")`, but that's using `AVERAGEIFS` for something that you can use `=AVERAGEIF`.

Comment: but i dont understand,in averageifs i can use multiple criteria right?what will be correct  format for averageifs  to avoid this *west?

Comment: can i use averageifs for calculate average for west and midwest?

Comment: @datodatuashvili `AVERAGEIFS` uses intersecting condition. The way you wrote the formula is looking for a single cell which is both equal to F6 AND equal to F9, which is impossible unless F6=F9. As I told you, you can use `=AVERAGEIFS(G5:G9,F5:F9,"=*West")` or `=AVERAGEIFS(G5:G9,F5:F9,"*"&F6)`, but those would calculate 'SouthWest' and/or 'Northwest' if they exist.

Comment: what does *west means?

Comment: @datodatuashvili `*` is a wildcard, it means that it matches anything. `*West` means that it will match anything ending with `West`.

Comment: you can use a wildcard it if you want the average for "west" and "midwest" beacuse they both contain `west`.....but it won't be any good if you want the average for west and north - I'd recommend Jerry's suggestion for a generic solution

Comment: FWIW you could also use an array formula with AVERAGE, i.e. `=AVERAGE(IF((F5:F9=F6)+(F5:F9=F9),G5:G9))` confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`